# how twitter rolled out night mode without updating ios client

Tags: ios, twitter, auto-update, ota

I noticed that twitter was last updated on 18th august and they rolled out night mode on 22nd august. then how that feature popped up in the ios client.
Please enlighten me if am missing on something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple potential options, but most likely it's simply a feature they implemented and is turned on and off by a server setting.

Comment: you mean they updated client UI as well from server setting? By using a flag?

Comment: The feature was implemented at some point in the past and just turned on, possibly they've been A/B testing it for a while.

Comment: i just checked change logs. night mode is mentioned in 18th aug update but am sure that the feature was not visible back then. so, i guess they turned it on yesterday after testing as mentioned by you.